# python xlwings I want to open a file as read only using the caller when opening the file normally has a dialog option for read only or password

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

When I call a file to be used in code. THat file has been read only protected and requires a password in order to write. I want to just read it so xlwings to open the file and pass by the read only dialog by hitting read only

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

def main():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    ws = wb.sheets["Engine"]
    wbDiners = xw.Book(ws["Diners"].value)

    

    dfRDiners = wbDiners.sheets["Invoice-Retail-Email"]["C1:H1000"].options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=False).value
```

[image: Click read only]

Answer (score 1):

`xw.Book` has a `read_only` parameter. Set it to `True` to get rid of the dialog:

```py
wbDiners = xw.Book(ws["Diners"].value, read_only=True)
```

See also: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Book